# Ruby: Get the class on which currently executing code is defined

Tags: ruby

How can I programmatically get the class on which the currently executing code is defined? I need to find the class when control flow runs through multiple method definitions due to `super()`:

```
class A
  def foo
    puts(get_current_class)
  end
end

class B < A
  def foo
    puts(get_current_class)
    super
  end
end

class C < B
  def foo
    puts(get_current_class)
    super
  end
end

C.new.foo
# => C
# => B
# => A
```

I know how to get the method name (using `__callee__`, `caller_locations` or `__method__`); but what about the class?

Answer (score 1):

Since classes in ruby are also modules, this could be achieved with [`Module#nesting`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-c-nesting):

```
class A
  def foo
    puts(Module.nesting.first)
  end
end

class B < A
  def foo
    puts(Module.nesting.first)
    super
  end
end

class C < B
  def foo
    puts(Module.nesting.first)
    super
  end
end

C.new.foo
# => C
# => B
# => A
```

Alternatively, if the goal is to construct a list of which methods may be called by the object's ancestor chain, then you could use [`Method#owner`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-owner) and [`Method#super_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-super_method) (available [since ruby version `2.2.0`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_0/NEWS#core-classes-updates-outstanding-ones-only)):

```
c = C.new
c.method(:foo).owner # => C
c.method(:foo).super_method.owner # => B
c.method(:foo).super_method.super_method.owner # => A
c.method(:foo).super_method.super_method.super_method # => nil
```

As a quick off-the-cuff implementation to programatically print all classes then, how about:

```
c = C.new
method = c.method(:foo)
while(method)
  puts m.owner
  method = method.super_method
end
# => C
# => B
# => A
```

(However, there is no guarantee that all of these methods will actually be invoked - as this is determined at runtime via `super`!)

Comment: However, I cannot even remotely imagine any situation in which one would actually need this. I mean, if you write a method `foo` in class `B`, then you know that you are in class `B`. It's right there on the top of your screen.

Comment: Yes, I agree... I'd almost certainly just write `puts "Called foo() from class B"` in the code, rather than doing it "programmatically" like the above! Maybe this is useful if you want to quickly place debug statements in loads of places, though.